# Magento 1.7 "Can not find web service adapter" Error Soap

Tags: web-services, api, magento, soap, magento-1.7

I have changed my server apache configuration and now I am having this error in the front end:

**"Can not find webservice adapter"**.

[image]

My problem is that this error is not documented and I can't find anything in Google. Does anyone knows how to fix this or how to debug it. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I didn't see error before like this..Make sure SOAP and REST php extensions are loaded..May this will fix your problem..

Comment: I have in the same server 10 magento instances just like this one and they are working. Is this a per site configuration?

Comment: I am not sure about this..I googled. But I didn't get any notable thing..I am expecting some other will post answer for this..

Comment: Isn't this the file that validates this error? Do you know what it does -> http://freegento.com/doc/d9/d92/_server_8php-source.html

Comment: Bad translations, I can't believe wasted all day on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a translation problem, I found out that many translation have does fields wrongly translated. It can happen that a plugin or a extension is overriding the same translation variable. Just change the administration to the original ENGLISH and you will notice that everything is ok.

Comment: Oh..Yesterday I was also messed out..I didn't think about that it could be translation problem..Anyway problem solved..Thanks for updating your answer..